# How to close the 3G network program?

Tags: ios

Are there any APIs to control the 3G Networks of a phone, I will be creating an app to close the 3g network.

Comment: If this is meant for the App Store then this definitely can't be done. I have no idea if this is possible for jailbroken devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm quite sure you can't do this. You can't alter the user's phone settings or connection.